# Possible to get "Owner" contact info in Android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I haven't been able to find a straight answer on this. Can anyone tell me if it's possible to get the contact info of the phone's owner in an Android App?

Comment: Do you mean the phone number? If so, you can use getLine1Number (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29) although it's not 100% reliable.

Comment: I'm looking for name and address

Comment: i was looking into this too, my app involves the user entering in their name, email, and phone number, which are all obviously stored in the phone already. i cant find the pages i was reading but everything said that all of the methods of getting that info were/are being deprecated and taken out of the newer apis for security reasons. you could always just ask the user for it and save the data in `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So the answer is technically no. The only way I've found so far to get owner's data is through the account manager. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
final AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
final Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
final int size = accounts.length;
String[] names = new String[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  names[i] = accounts[i].name;
}
```

For more info see: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/AndroidAccountManager

Comment: Is Possible to update “Owner” contact info in Android?

Answer (score 13):

I have found a very easy way (got it from digging into the 4.1 Messaging app!)

projection for cursor is

```
final String[] SELF_PROJECTION = new String[] { Phone._ID,Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, };
```

Cursor is :

```
Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(Profile.CONTENT_URI, SELF_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
```

now just do a simple

```
cursor.moveToFirst():
```

and then fetch the contact id via

```
cursor.getString(0)
```

and the contact name via

```
cursor.getString(1)
```

and..... you're done!

Comment: This method is only supported in Android 4.0 (API 14) or later. So if you only care about using this on 20-25% of devices, then it can work for you.

Comment: @Daniel, your comment was broadly true at the time you wrote it - but it's only gonna get more popular. And Daksh's code works a treat, as long as you surround it with `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH`. Enough search queries hone in on this response that we should promote it for the future!

Comment: Note that you'll need to add 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` lest you get hit by `SecurityException`

Comment: Is Possible to update “Owner” contact info in Android?

Comment: This needs the right READ_CONTACTS. Since apps requiring this permission are dubios, this isn't a good solution. Actually, the right to read ALL contacts must not be necessary in order to read the name only of the OWNER of the phone.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the Phone._ID field will be equivalent to the ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_ID for the profile contact?

Answer (score 6):

What we have to do:

1) Get user synchronization account name (which is usually google email)
2) Get contact from contact book with this email
3) Get contact data from this contact

Not even close to perfect, and needs two additional permissions - but at least works.

Here's the code, possible code updates can be here:
https://gist.github.com/3904299

```
import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;

public class OwnerInfo {
    // this class allows to get device information. It's done in two steps:
    // 1) get synchronization account email
    // 2) get contact data, associated with this email
    // by https://github.com/jehy
    //WARNING! You need to have permissions
    //
    //<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    //<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    //
    // in your AndroidManifest.xml for this code.

    public String id = null;
    public String email = null;
    public String phone = null;
    public String accountName = null;
    public String name = null;

    public OwnerInfo(Activity MainActivity) {
        final AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(MainActivity);
        final Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        if (accounts[0].name != null) {
            accountName = accounts[0].name;

            ContentResolver cr = MainActivity.getContentResolver();
            Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " = ?",
                    new String[] { accountName }, null);
            while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                id = emailCur
                        .getString(emailCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID));
                email = emailCur
                        .getString(emailCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                String newName = emailCur
                        .getString(emailCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (name == null || newName.length() > name.length())
                    name = newName;

                Log.v("Got contacts", "ID " + id + " Email : " + email
                        + " Name : " + name);
            }

            emailCur.close();
            if (id != null) {

                // get the phone number
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    phone = pCur
                            .getString(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Log.v("Got contacts", "phone" + phone);
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is useful to get profile info from table. Is it possible to update profile info?

Comment: @neerajkirola If you mean updating user's contacts - yes, it it possible if you have the permission to manage contacts. It is discussed in other questions, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603187/modify-native-contact-programmatically

Comment: Is Possible to update “Owner” contact info in Android?

Comment: @neerajkirola it is just another contact in user's contacts, why not.

Comment: Thanks for continuous replying my query...could u pls put that code here to update owner profile (name, contact number etc.) Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @neerajkirola This is offtopic, but you can check this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907751/android-update-a-contact

Answer (score 4):

For Ice Cream Sandwich or later, using

```
String[] columnNames = new String[] {Profile.DISPLAY_NAME, Profile.PHOTO_ID};

Cursor c = activity.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, columnNames, null, null, null);
int count = c.getCount();
boolean b = c.moveToFirst();
int position = c.getPosition();
if (count == 1 && position == 0) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) {
        String name = c.getString(0));
        long photoId = c.getLong(1));
    }
}
c.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

From API 23 and above you need to add proper permission in manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

Then you will be able to retrieve user info like,

```
String[] columnNames = new String[] {ContactsContract.Profile.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Profile.PHOTO_ID};

Cursor c = activity.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, columnNames, null, null, null);
int count = c.getCount();
boolean b = c.moveToFirst();
int position = c.getPosition();
if (count == 1 && position == 0) {
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String photoID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.PHOTO_ID));
        Log.i("MainActivity", "name: " + name);
        Log.i("MainActivity", "photoID: "+ photoID);
    }
}
c.close()
```