# Modify native contact programmatically

Tags: android, contacts

I'm trying to modify contact first name and last name programmatically.
The code snippet that I've used in order to do the job is the following one:

```java
operations.add( ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate( Data.CONTENT_URI )
  .withSelection( RawContacts._ID + "=?",
  new String[] { String.valueOf( mSmartphoneContactKey) } )
    .withValue( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
     mContactName.getEditableText().toString() )
      .withValue( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,
        mContactLastName.getEditableText().toString() )                          
        .build() );
```

The `mSmartphoneContactKey` is filled in with the data contained in the column

```
ContactsContract.Contacts._ID
```

which is sitting in my projection array when I read contacts using content provider.

The problem is that for some contacts the name and last name are not modified and the phone type is modified instead.
Actually I don't have any clue about the cause.
Any advice is appreciated.

---

I've read further the documentation the Data table is the one I have to use.
I've modified the code as below...still not working

```
        operations.add( ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate( Data.CONTENT_URI )
                .withSelection( Data._ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                         new String[] { String.valueOf( mSmartphoneContactId ) } )
                         .withValue( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, mContactName.getEditableText().toString() )
                         .withValue( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, mContactLastName.getEditableText().toString() )                            
                         .build() );
```

Please help me!

Comment: I can able to get the native contact along with contact id.But i am facing problem in editing the same contact and deleting the same contact using the contact id. How can i solve this.

Comment: Here what is "mSmartphoneContactId"..whether it refers Data.ID or RawContacts._ID. please tell me

Comment: Please share the code to add contact into native contact and how to get that id and using that id how to edit and delete the contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Solved!
Wrong ID passed.
Need to retrieve the ID along the data from the DATA table.