# How to get owner infomation from android device programatically?

Tags: android

I want my android application to take automatically owner name from deice. So, how I get the owner information (like owner name) from android device.

Comment: do you need device information like name, model, android version and else?

Comment: No, i want device owner name.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you get the owner name stored in the device

```
Cursor c = getApplication().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null); 
c.moveToFirst();
textView.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("display_name")));
c.close();
```

make sure to add this permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: then use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222384/possible-to-get-owner-contact-info-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link for accessing the device related information

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

if you want to get the playstore user account information you have to use the firebase play service api to get the account information

Please refer this link for more reference
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users