# Why is no user profile returned on Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-user-profile

I'm using a bit of code to get the ID of the current user's profile:

```
val cursor = contentResolver.query(
    ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
    arrayOf(ContactsContract.Profile._ID),
    null,
    null,
    null
)

cursor.moveToFirst()

val id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile._ID))
cursor.close()
```

On my Galaxy S7 device running Android 8.0.0 (API level 26) this works properly, but on the Nexus 5X emulator also running 8.0.0, I get `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`, implying that there is no user profile present.

My understanding was that since API 14 [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12898589/5374919) was guaranteed to return the user's profile, which exists by default. Why then is there no result?

Comment: Why did you think that?  There's no requirement for it at all.  A content provider will return an answer to a query.  A fact like that would be implementation specific.  Not all phones use the same contacts app.  There is no assurance of having a self contact.

Comment: Your have no guarantee that any data will be returned. The  method `movetoFirst()` returns a boolean value indicating whether there is data or not. Only if it returns `true` should you continue.