# Android - Profile CONTENT_URI returning zero count cursor

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

According to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12898589/1084174), I want to get the profile info of the device owner in Android contact.

```
String[] columnNames = new String[] {ContactsContract.Profile.DISPLAY_NAME};
Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, columnNames, null, null, null);
int count = c.getCount();
```

Permissions are added in manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
```

I have added valid name and number in contact. I am getting `count = 0.`, My expectation is to get nonzero count. What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56230915/1084174), AndroidManifest.xml should include the proper permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```