# Manifest.permission.READ_PROFILE not found

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, contacts, user-profile

While working on an Android application I am required to grant permission for reading/writing for contacts and profile. I found Android manifest file have possible permissions like,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_PROFILE"/>
```

And I am able to show request runtime permission for Contacts i.e.,

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
```

However when I put below code, It says `READ_PROFILE` is not found.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PROFILE},
        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PROFILE);
```

How can I request runtime permission for reading/writing profile. I am using,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

But after editing profile info, when I save it does not update the profile rather shows a toast like,

> Nothing to save. Contact discarded

Is it a permission issue? How can I update profile info successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`READ_PROFILE` permission was removed on API 23 as stated here:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html

Use `GET_ACCOUNTS` instead.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#perm-groups